# MYSQL Insert values into another table if values not exists

Tags: mysql

I am writing from one Mysql table to another, and I need to check if the values I am inserting already exist. I have tried setting indexes on the two columns I am checking values (`onhand`.`Sales_Order` & `onhand`.`SKU`)

Here is my query:

```
INSERT INTO onhand(Sales_Order, SKU, Inventory, Time)
  SELECT Sales_Order, Part_Number, '0', Now() AS DateTimeStamp from 
  fullfillment_sage WHERE New_OnHand IN (-1, 0, 'NULL') OR New_OnHand IS NULL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
  `fullfillment_sage`.`Sales_Order`, 
  `fullfillment_sage`.`Part_Number`
   FROM `fullfillment_sage`
   LEFT JOIN `onhand`
   ON `fullfillment_sage`.`Sales_Order` = `onhand`.`Sales_Order`
   AND `fullfillment_sage`.`Part_Number` = `onhand`.`SKU` 
   WHERE `fullfillment_sage`.`New_OnHand` IN (-1, 0, 'NULL') OR 
   `fullfillment_sage`.`New_OnHand` IS NULL);
```

The query errors here:

```
 'WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT `fullfillment_sage`.`Sales_Order`,
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT

Comment: `insert` does not support `where`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to 'insert if not exists' in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql)

Comment: agreed, googled this first, replace into and ignore into does not seem to be a plausible sceanrio due to current structure

Comment: Where not supported on an insert?!?!   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html then why do doc's show it in an example!?  The problem is you have  2 where statements.. put the first in ()'s and change the 2nd to an and.

Comment: agreed with @xQbert - where clause is supported on an insert.

Comment: and @MatthewColley  ok... so what is 'NULL' for new_onhand is it really a 'NULL' string or is it a null value we need to handle?  and one last question: you are CREATING a new table right (onhand?)  if not then `SELECT ... INTO TABLE creates a NEW table with the rows from the SELECT, this is completely different from INSERT ... SELECT, which just appends rows to an existing table.` per  usercomment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two where statements in your outer select.  Wrap your or in ()'s for the first one and change the 2nd where to an and.

```
INSERT INTO onhand(Sales_Order, SKU, Inventory, Time)
  SELECT Sales_Order
       , Part_Number
       , 0
       , Now() AS DateTimeStamp 
  FROM fullfillment_sage 
  WHERE (New_OnHand IN (-1, 0, 'NULL') OR New_OnHand IS NULL)
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT `fullfillment_sage`.`Sales_Order`
                         , `fullfillment_sage`.`Part_Number`
                    FROM `fullfillment_sage`
                    LEFT JOIN `onhand`
                      ON `fullfillment_sage`.`Sales_Order` = `onhand`.`Sales_Order`
                     AND `fullfillment_sage`.`Part_Number` = `onhand`.`SKU` 
                    WHERE `fullfillment_sage`.`New_OnHand` IN (-1, 0, 'NULL') 
                      OR  `fullfillment_sage`.`New_OnHand` IS NULL);
```

This assumes there are no other issues with the select, I've not looked closely enough yet.

I don't think inventory of string '0' should be inserted I think it should be 0. though implicit casting is probably helping you there.

maybe new_onhand needs to elimninate 'null' since you have the or.... or you could change `(New_OnHand IN (-1, 0, 'NULL') OR New_OnHand IS NULL)` to...
`coalesce(New_OnHand,0) IN (-1, 0)`  if New_Onhand is null set it to zero and make sure new_onhand is either -1 or 0.

Answer (score 0):

As @juergend d mentioned in the comments, `insert` does not support `where`. I suggest you to create an if-statement that checks if this dataset exists. If not, execute the inesert query.